# Visual Studio debugging stopped at non-break point code

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

It is wild. I have not set a break point in the code, however it stopped at the line that was no break point. Let me demo this in a C# console application project.

[image: demo]

When I clicked F5, it stopped at line 29. Clicking it again, then stopped at line 33....

The debug option is:

[image: step2]

**UPDATED**

It could load an irrelevant symbol file. See below. How to disable it?

[image: symbol]

Comment: Just to be sure: your program compiled before you ran it? Or is it possible you run an older build and have newer source code?

Comment: I clear the solution and rebuild it, still wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct file?  If you turn off check sum matching VS will display this behavrio because it only matches on file name which can easily lead to using eralier versions of the file

Comment: Sorry I am not following you. I just copied and pasted code, it is same as manually typing code.

Comment: Do you build and run a Debug configuration? Open the Modules window (Debug -> Window -> Modules), check path to your loaded program and symbol file of program. Probably there have been loaded the wrong symbol files.

Comment: Try deleting the *.suo file. The *.suo file is where the breakpoints are stored.

Comment: It suddenly disappeared this morning and load some symbol file. See my updated please.

Answer (score 2):

VS sometimes does not correctly remove its breakpoints. The solution is to use debug > remove all breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have a directory configured in the Cache symbols directory.
Go to Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols.
If there is a directory that already set automaticly, shut down visual studio and delet it (or rename it if you wanna roll back from some reason).
It worked for me.
Dan.